# Application windows have colossal fonts in Enlightenment 17, while system windows are untouched

Tags: linux, enlightenment

I'm trying to get used to using Enlightenment instead of KDE on my Slackware64 multilib computer, but I'm having a terrible time getting one problem fixed.

My fonts are HUGE on application windows - from Firefox to Gimp to Xchat to anything else, all the fonts are 3x the size they should be.

But at the same time, the system menu is the correct size. I'm at a loss - I want the applications to have the same DPI as the system menu. When I'm in KDE, they all look normal.

I've included a screenshot to show what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Slackware64, but on Bodhilinux and Sabayon there is an lxappearance package.
So, you have to install it, launch and in "widget" tab choose "default font" that suits you.